# What's up with this path? Error: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: javascript, redux, multer, mern

I try to upload an article with image, and the redux devtools telling me the error above. Obviously it wants to use

> C:\xampp\frontside\public\uploads\

The correct path wood be

> C:\xampp\htdocs\mern_redux_ntv\frontside\public\uploads\

The path I have used in my multer-storage is correct. I have tried an absolute path. I tried http://localhost:3000/frontside/public/uploads. I tried it only with /public. But I have no file in my folder and there is nothing uploaded to cloudinary.

Here is my backend:

```
router.post("/", upload.single("img"), verifyTokenAndAuthorization, async (req,res)=>{
        const {img, ressort, theme, title, content} = req.body;
    try{
        const uploadResult = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(img,{
            upload_preset: "Mern_redux-practice",
            resource_type: "auto",
        }).then ((result)=>{
            console.log("Upload successfull", JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
            res.status(200).json(result)
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log("error", JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
        });
```

Here is my multer-storage:

```
const multer = require("multer");

 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination:(req,file, callback)=>{
            callback(null, '../../frontside/public/uploads')
        },
        fileName: (req, file, callback)=>{
            callback(null, Date.now()+ "--"+ file.originalname)
        }
    })

const upload = multer({storage:storage});

module.exports = upload;
```

My http-request:

```
const createMainNews = async (mainnewsData, token)=>{
    const config = {
        headers: {
            // 'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data`,
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
             token: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
    }
    const response = await axios.post(API_URL, mainnewsData, config);
    console.log(response);
    return response.data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution by myself. It is important to put a static path into the index.js or server.js. When you want to store your image in the public folder of the frontend than it is the following:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'frontside/public/')));
```

And in multer it is:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination:(req,file, callback)=>{
            callback(null,  path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'frontside/public/uploads'));
        },
        fileName: (req, file, callback)=>{
            callback(null, Date.now()+ "--"+ path.extname(file.originalname));
        }
    })

const upload = multer({storage:storage});

module.exports = upload;
```